# How to prevent user from selecting date above end date in react-dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-range, react-dates

I'm wondering how I could prevent a user from selecting dates above today's date. For example, today is 3.7 so let that be the highest end date a user could select.

```
<DateRangePicker
    startDate={this.state.startDate} 
    startDateId="startDate" 
    endDate={this.state.endDate} 
    endDateId="endDate" 
    onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => {
      this.setState({ startDate, endDate }, () => {});
    }} 
    focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
    onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    daySize={50}
    noBorder={true}
    isOutsideRange={() => false}
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an [`isOutsideRange`](https://airbnb.io/projects/react-dates/) prop and [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for working with available dates ranges. For example, you can allow selecting only dates within a past 30 days this way:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dubinsky-igqsh?fontsize=14)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-dates";
import { START_DATE, END_DATE } from "react-dates/constants";

export default class Dates extends Component {
  state = {
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    focusedInput: null
  };

  onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) =>
    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });

  onFocusChange = focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput });

  isOutsideRange = day =>
    day.isAfter(moment()) || day.isBefore(moment().subtract(30, "days"));

  render() {
    const { startDate, endDate, focusedInput } = this.state;

    return (
      <DateRangePicker
        startDate={startDate}
        startDateId={START_DATE}
        endDate={endDate}
        endDateId={END_DATE}
        onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
        focusedInput={focusedInput}
        onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
        daySize={50}
        noBorder={true}
        isOutsideRange={this.isOutsideRange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if you found the solution. But I gave my solution anyway.

You can use import `{ isInclusivelyBeforeDay }` from react-dates and use `isOutsideRange={day => !isInclusivelyBeforeDay(day, moment())}`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on another react date picker package.
After a bit of reading the documentation for yours (the AirBnb one) I was able to find this issue being mentionned on their GitHub:
[Set date range #86](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/86)

It appears there is a prop called `isOutsideRange` that takes a function. You could return `false` for any date outside of the current date for example, with just a comparison.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**function**

```
isOutsideRange(day) {
    return (moment().diff(day) < 0);
  }
```

...

```
<DateRangePicker
isOutsideRange={this.isOutsideRange}
>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not clear what your question is. Please formulate a proper question, and learn how to format your code a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest date range picker version, I just used `maxDate={new Date()}`. This worked fine to me. This didn't allow me to select more than today.